# How linq to nhibernate by join and Separate where in query

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, join, linq-to-nhibernate

I have 3 classes : Person, Employee1 , Employee2

```
public class Employee1 : Person
{
}

public class Employee2 : Person
{
}
```

I need to a query on Person_Table that some time need to join Employee1_Table or Employee_Table.

```
var q = SessionInstance.Query<Person>();

if (dto.Code != null)                           // A1 Condition
     q = q.Where(x => x.Code == dto.Code);

//if(A2 Condition)
//if(A3 Condition)
//...

switch (dto.Type)
{
    case PersonType.Employee1:
         var q1 = SessionInstance.Query<Employee1>();
         q.Join(q1, x => x.Id, xx => xx.Id, (x, xx) => x);

         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dto.Unit))   // B1 Condition
             q1 = q1.Where(xx => xx.Unit == dto.Unit);

         //if(B2 Condition)
         //if(B3 Condition)
         //... 

         return q1.ToList<Person>();

    case PersonType.Employee2:
         var q2 = SessionInstance.Query<Employee2>();
         q.Join(q2, x => x.Id, xx => xx.Id, (x, xx) => x);

         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dto.Serial)) // C1 Condition
             q2 = q2.Where(xx => xx.Serial == dto.Serial);

         //if(C2 Condition)
         //if(C3 Condition)
         //... 

         return q2.ToList<Person>();

    default:
         return q.ToList();
}
```

This query for join has incomplete. If **dto.Type** equals by **PersonType.Employee1** or **PersonType.Employee2**, `A1 , A2 , ...` does not affect. But for default case of switch `A1 , A2 , ...` has effect on query. 
My Where conditions in 3 separate classes is many and I need to add `Where` conditions of query separately. Why?

**UPDATE :**

```
var q = SessionInstance.Query<Person>();

if (dto.Code != null)                           // A1 Condition
     q = q.Where(x => x.Code == dto.Code);

//if(A2 Condition)
//if(A3 Condition)
//...

 var q1 = SessionInstance.Query<Employee1>();

 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dto.Unit))   // B1 Condition
     q1 = q1.Where(xx => xx.Unit == dto.Unit);

 //if(B2 Condition)
 //if(B3 Condition)
 //... 

 return q.Join(q1, x => x.Id, xx => xx.Id, (x, xx) => x).ToList<Person>();
```

This updated query has a exception if `B1` condition is true. Message of this exception is : **Specified method is not supported.**

**Stack Trace is :**

```
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.PolymorphicQuerySourceDetector.GetClassName(IASTNode querySource)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.PolymorphicQuerySourceDetector.Process(IASTNode tree)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.AstPolymorphicProcessor.Process()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IASTNode ast, String queryIdentifier, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String queryIdentifier, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery)
   at NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Remotion.Data.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the non-default switch cases, you return q1 and q2, respectively. These queries are never assigned with anything that involves q, which explains why the Ax conditions aren't present in the final query.

Also, consider the row:

```
q.Join(q1, x => x.Id, xx => xx.Id, (x, xx) => x);
```

As with all LINQ methods, the Join method() will not affect q or q1 in any way, but instead return a new IQueryable. The code as written ignores this return value, so the line will have no effect on the final query.

You have the correct pattern everywhere else, that is: "q = q.Something....".

You will have to change the Join() to return new {x, xx} in its last parameter, so that you can move the .Where() call from q1 to q, and still have access to the item from q1. Something like:

```
var qJoined = q.Join(SessionInstance.Query<Employee1>(),
                     x => x.Id, xx => xx.Id,
                     (x, xx) => new {x, xx});

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dto.Unit))   // B1 Condition
    qJoined = qJoined.Where(w => w.xx.Unit == dto.Unit);

return qJoined.Select(w => w.x).ToList();
```

Comment: @Berggren So How can I do it?

Comment: Edited with suggestions on how to proceed.

Comment: I move q1.Where() before q.Join() and return q.ToList() instead of q1.ToList(). Now q.Where() has effect on query but q1.Where does not affect. Also I changed q.Join() to q=q.Join(), if dto.Unit equals null still q1.Where does not affect and if dto.Unit has value, This Code Has a exception by this message `Specified method is not supported.`

Comment: Your if-statement will prevent the additional where-clause from being added if dto.Unit is null, so this is as expected. As for the exceptions, which method is not supported? And where is the exception generated?

Comment: I've edited the question to remove the first suggestions, since I think such a query would require a subquery in the from-clause of the generated SQL, which NHibernate can't handle. But what is it that you are trying to achieve here? Return Employee1 instances instead of the "pure" Person instances from the first query? Or return only persons for which there is a matching Employee1?

Comment: My purpos of this join query is : return only persons for which there is a matching Employee1 Where conditions.
And exception throw by replacement q=q.Join() instead of q.Join() when B1 condition is done and where Execute of q.ToList().
Also your solution is usefull when join and Where condition are togther `q.Join().Where(w=>w.x. ..)`
for seperate Where conditions, `w.x & w.xx` is unknown

Comment: For that purpose, the example query I added in my last edit seems suitable. Which method is not supported? Not which method you called when it happened, because very much can happen behind the scenes. Please post the full exception details to the question. If x and xx is available when you chain the .Where call, but unknown in a separate .Where(), it sounds like you've forgotten to do the "q = q.Join()" part. But this is getting confusing. Please update the question with your best attempt so far, and we can take it from there.

Comment: The code you posted now contains my first suggestion, which I later removed from my answer because I realised it would require a subquery in the from-clause. This isn't supported by NHibernate, hence the exception. Try my second suggestion instead (which has the code sample in my answer above).

Comment: Second your solution has two build errors :

`1)` Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Person>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

`2)` 'Person' does not contain a definition for 'xx' and no extension method 'xx' accepting a first argument of type 'Person' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Yes, the Join() will return a differently typed IQueryable, so we need a new variable for that. I've updated the code to account for this.